# How to get sql statement to search for a percent sign?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dreamweaver

I have a sql statement that is searching my database

```
"SELECT catelogue.ARTIST, catelogue.TITLE, catelogue.`CAT NO.`, 
catelogue.FORMAT,catelogue.`IMAGE PATH` 
FROM catelogue 
WHERE catelogue.TITLE LIKE '%$search%'"
```

Now I understand in sql that your percent is your wildcard but I now need the search to search for 100% Summer because this is the title of a cd.

Is there a way to do this so that the percent sign dosn't affect my other wildcards?

EDIT:

So if I use this

```
$search = addcslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($search), '%_');
```

Is there then any need for preg replace

```
$search = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9\/\\+\.,:?-]+/", "", $search)
```

And can preg replace be used in conjunction with mysql_real_escape_string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\%`  is an escaped “%” character.

**Edited**:

PHP:

```
$search = "100\% Summer";
```

in general use [`string addcslashes ( string $str , string $charlist )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php):

```
$search = "100% Summer";
$search = addcslashes($search, '%_');
```

Don't forget to use [`string mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier ] )`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent SQL injection. So the final code might looks like:

```
$search = "100% Summer";
$search = addcslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($search), '%_');
```

Comment: `addslashes` only adds slashes to single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash (\) and NUL.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the wildcard characters using `\`, for example with
`str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('\%', '\_'), $subject)`.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT catelogue.ARTIST, catelogue.TITLE, catelogue.`CAT NO.`, 
catelogue.FORMAT,catelogue.`IMAGE PATH` 
FROM catelogue 
WHERE catelogue.TITLE LIKE '%100\% Summer%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape percent sign with backslash

```
$search = str_replace('%', '\%', $search);

...

WHERE catelogue.TITLE LIKE '%$search%'
```

By the way, if your `$search` comes from the user input, then your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Yea I know about sql injection where someone could drop my table so it is running through a preg replace function

Comment: @user A preg replace function against SQL injection?!